# Adding screenshot in iTunes Connect without real Device

Tags: xcode, submit, ios-simulator, screenshot, app-store-connect

I am about to submit my app in iTunes connect.

Now it is asking me for screenshots for a 3.5-inch, 4-inch, 4.7-inch and 5.5-inch.

Since I coded it in swift I guess I can skip the 3.5inch part?

But my question is: I only have an 4-inch device available. How can I add the screenshots of the 4.7 and 6inch? maybe with the simulator?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the iOS Simulator File > Screenshot

That saves a screenshot to your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Simulator should be fine. You can edit it using Sketch, I found it really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few different methods, and what worked best for me in a short amount of time was to capture screenshots in the iOS Simulator at 100% scale and then resize them using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), which is free unlike Sketch.

If you're in the business of creating screenshots for many devices, across locales or with frequent screenshot update needs it's best to look into automation with tool like [Snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot/).